# Can the same dropbox oauth access token be used from different apps/servers?

Tags: oauth-2.0, dropbox, dropbox-api

**Note: cross-posted from Dropbox forums**

I am developing an application in which users authorize Dropbox on the main website, but the actual interaction with the API (downloading/uploading) files happens on a separate worker server (currently running on my localhost).

However, I am able to do the Dropbox OAuth flow without problems, however whenever I try to use the access_token on my local app, I get the following error:

```
dropbox.rest.ErrorResponse: [401] u"The given OAuth 2 access token doesn't exist or has expired."
```

Is there a restriction on how access tokens can be used? are they bound to the same domain or IP?

More info:
- Where auth happens: beta.company-domain.com
- Where token is used: comand-line python app running in my local box

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, link to the Dropbox forum posting: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=109971.

Comment: As a side note, I found that my original problem was due to one side using OAuth1 and the other OAuth2!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no restrictions on where you can use an OAuth token. Once you have the token, you should be able to use it from anywhere. (I do this all the time, generating tokens via https://dbxoauth2.site44.com and then using them with `curl` or the like.) I would verify that you're really using the same OAuth token and that it hasn't been somehow mangled in the process of moving it.